# What is the 4th factor in 4 factor authentication

Tags: authentication, two-factor-authentication

The Principle for 3-Factor authentication is

Something you have (like a smartcard)
Something you know (like a pin)
Something you are (like a fingerprint)

Then what is the 4th factor. Is it like 4D :)

Comment: It could be argued that fingerprint is "something you have" or "something you know" and as such would only add repeation of existing factor. I know that using a fingerprint scanner is generally considered as 3rd factor but the fact is that it's only static data that is supposedly fetched from the fingerprint scanner (as opposed from a piece of software or from static file on hard drive). Any authentication secret that cannot be replaced at will (potentially compromised) is a really poor secret.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen my question on Security.SE yet but related: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/68009/28137

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think 4-factor authentication is a well defined concept - it'd just be called "multi-factor".

Probably somewhere you **are**! You can only log in if you and device are in a certain location, for example.

Answer (score 2):

THe 4 are something you know (e.g. password), something you have (e.g. card) something you are (biometric), and more recently  where you are (location).

Note that one can argue biometric are really something you know (behiavorial like signature) or something you have physical  (finger/face) that are simply harder to share/steal.  As Mikko points out, non-revocable biometrics are weak because they cannot be cancled, new revocable ones are better.

The new 4th factor, my location,  is still controversial, useful when used in conjunction as others since it makes it harder to spoof when I am in say Colorado springs this am, and someone tries to authenticate as me in Nigeria this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Four factor authentication is a series of having 4 levels

Level 1. Passwords
Level 2. Smart Cards
Level 3. Bio-metrics
Level 4. GPS